# restore my project in android studio from phone app

Tags: android-studio, restore

My notebook died and I lost all my data and my Android Studio projects. Only what I have left is apps in my phone. Is it somehow possible to restore it in Android Studio from my phone app? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: somehow get the original files back. You could try to:

- See if the drive still works by putting it into another system
- Search for some kind of backup (backup utility/cloud storage/github)
- Get some professional to rescue your data (if everything fails)

Option 2: decompiling

I just tried decompiling one of my apps [here](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) and it kind of worked. You may have to remember your project structure somehow, but in the end, I think it's doable for smaller app projects.

Disclaimer: never decompile other people's software without their permission.

Comment: I did not manage to save any data :( but for rebuilding my app I used show java app and it kind of work. Thank you